# Bug Affecting Entity Movement in Java Game Development

Tags: java, game-development

I am working through a tutorial from Youtube on how to make a 2D style game in Java ([Click here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=om59cwR7psI&list=PL_QPQmz5C6WUF-pOQDsbsKbaBZqXj4qSq&index=1&ab_channel=RyiSnow) for Video 1, though I am currently working on video #20)

I recently tried to add Event Tiles that cause the player to teleport/heal/take damage. I no longer have the teleport option while troubleshooting, but essentially what is happening when I start the game is that my player spawns where it should, but when I press any directional key, I am instantly transported to the top left tile and I have no clue why.

I've narrowed it down to my checkEvent method, which I will post below.

Please let me know if I can post more code, I also have  a KeyHandler, Entity, Player, and Event Rectangle classes, but in troubleshooting, it wasnt until I took away the checkEvent method below that I was able to move again.

```
package main;
public class EventHandler {
    GamePanel gp;
    EventRect eventRect[][];

    int previousEventX, previousEventY;
    boolean canTouchEvent = true;

    public EventHandler(GamePanel gp) {
        this.gp = gp;

        eventRect = new EventRect[gp.maxWorldCol][gp.maxWorldRow];

        int col = 0;
        int row = 0;

        while (col < gp.maxWorldCol && row < gp.maxWorldRow) {

            eventRect[col][row] = new EventRect();
            eventRect[col][row].x = 23;
            eventRect[col][row].y = 23;
            eventRect[col][row].width = 2;
            eventRect[col][row].height = 2;
            eventRect[col][row].eventRectDefaultX = eventRect[col][row].x;
            eventRect[col][row].eventRectDefaultY = eventRect[col][row].y;

            col++;
            if (col == gp.maxWorldCol) {
                col = 0;
                row++;
            }
        }
    }

    public void checkEvent() {

        //check if character is one tile away from  last event
        int xDistance = Math.abs(gp.player.worldX = previousEventX);
        int yDistance = Math.abs(gp.player.worldY = previousEventY);
        int distance = Math.max(xDistance, yDistance);
        if (distance > gp.tileSize) {
            canTouchEvent = true;
        }

        if(canTouchEvent == true) {
            if (hit(27, 16, "any") == true) {damagePit(27, 16, gp.dialogueState);}
            if (hit(27, 18, "any") == true) {healingPool(27, 18, gp.dialogueState);}
        }
    }

    public boolean hit(int col, int row, String reqDirection) {

        boolean hit = false;
        gp.player.solidArea.x = gp.player.worldX + gp.player.solidArea.x;
        gp.player.solidArea.y = gp.player.worldY + gp.player.solidArea.y;
        eventRect[col][row].x = col*gp.tileSize + eventRect[col][row].x;
        eventRect[col][row].y = row*gp.tileSize + eventRect[col][row].y;

        if (gp.player.solidArea.intersects(eventRect[col][row]) && eventRect[col][row].eventDone == false) {
            if (gp.player.direction.contentEquals(reqDirection) || reqDirection.contentEquals("any")) {
                hit = true;

                previousEventX = gp.player.worldX;
                previousEventY = gp.player.worldY;
            }
        }

        gp.player.solidArea.x = gp.player.solidAreaDefaultX;
        gp.player.solidArea.y = gp.player.solidAreaDefaultY;
        eventRect[col][row].x = eventRect[col][row].eventRectDefaultX;
        eventRect[col][row].y = eventRect[col][row].eventRectDefaultY;


        return hit;
    }

    /*public void teleport(int col, int row, int gameState) {
        gp.gameState = gp.gameState;
        gp.ui.currentDialogue = "NYOOM";
        gp.player.worldX = gp.tileSize * 17;
        gp.player.worldY = gp.tileSize * 20;
        canTouchEvent = false;
    }
     */
    public void damagePit(int col, int row, int gameState) {
        gp.gameState = gameState;
        gp.ui.currentDialogue = "MWAHA! You dun messed up";
        gp.player.life -= 1;
        //eventRect[col][row].eventDone = true;
        canTouchEvent = true;
    }
    public void healingPool(int col, int row, int gameState) {
        if (gp.keyH.enterPressed == true) {
            gp.gameState = gameState;
            gp.ui.currentDialogue = "Ahh, moistness";
            gp.player.life = gp.player.maxLife;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my first time posting, so if there is etiquette I am not following, please let me know :)

Comment: The lines `int xDistance = Math.abs(gp.player.worldX = previousEventX);` and `int yDistance = Math.abs(gp.player.worldY = previousEventY);` look wrong. Are you sure you didn't intend to write `int xDistance = Math.abs(gp.player.worldX - previousEventX);` and `int yDistance = Math.abs(gp.player.worldY - previousEventY);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `checkEvent()` method is wrong:

```
public void checkEvent() {

    //check if character is one tile away from  last event
    int xDistance = Math.abs(gp.player.worldX = previousEventX);
    int yDistance = Math.abs(gp.player.worldY = previousEventY);
    int distance = Math.max(xDistance, yDistance);
    if (distance > gp.tileSize) {
        canTouchEvent = true;
    }

    if(canTouchEvent == true) {
        if (hit(27, 16, "any") == true) {damagePit(27, 16, gp.dialogueState);}
        if (hit(27, 18, "any") == true) {healingPool(27, 18, gp.dialogueState);}
    }
}
```

In the line `int xDistance = Math.abs(gp.player.worldX = previousEventX);` you are assigning the current value of `previousEventX` (which is 0) to `gp.player.worldX` (which transports the player to the X coordinate 0) and sets the `xDistance` to 0 (because you calculate `Math.abs(0)`).

The next line for the `yDistance` is similar.

Change those two lines to

```
    int xDistance = Math.abs(gp.player.worldX - previousEventX);
    int yDistance = Math.abs(gp.player.worldY - previousEventY);
```

Comment: That was it!! Thank you!! I was losing my mind at this. I really appreciate the help!